# Kotlin date time format exception

Tags: kotlin, date

I have this time `2023-07-17T12:05:11.03831+00:00`

I try to parse it by this pattern

```kotlin
val formatPattern =
            DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                    .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")
                    .parseLenient()
                    .parseCaseInsensitive()
                    .appendOffset("+HH:MM", "+00:00")
                    .toFormatter()
val date = LocalDateTime.parse("2023-07-17T12:05:11.03831+00:00", formatPattern)
```

The problem is that some time it is parsed and some time it throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
Text '2023-07-17T12:05:11.03831+00:00' could not be parsed at index 20
```

It is work on Android Studio:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Kotlin 1.8.20

This does not work on some devices. This does not work on Kotlin online compiler

[example](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS43LjIxIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJjb2RlIjoiaW1wb3J0IGphdmEudGltZS5ab25lSWRcbmltcG9ydCBqYXZhLnRpbWUuWm9uZWREYXRlVGltZVxuaW1wb3J0IGphdmEudGltZS5mb3JtYXQuRGF0ZVRpbWVGb3JtYXR0ZXJcbmltcG9ydCBqYXZhLnV0aWwuTG9jYWxlXG5pbXBvcnQgamF2YS50aW1lLkxvY2FsRGF0ZVRpbWVcbmltcG9ydCBqYXZhLnRpbWUuZm9ybWF0LkRhdGVUaW1lRm9ybWF0dGVyQnVpbGRlclxuXG5mdW4gbWFpbigpIHtcbiAgICBwcmludGxuKGdldEZvcm1hdERhdGUoXCIyMDIzLTA3LTE3VDEyOjA1OjExLjAzODMxKzAwOjAwXCIpKVxufVxuXG5wcml2YXRlIGZ1biBnZXRGb3JtYXREYXRlKGRhdGU6IFN0cmluZyk6IExvY2FsRGF0ZVRpbWUge1xuICAgIHZhbCBkYXRlVGltZUZvcm1hdHRlciA9XG4gICAgICAgIERhdGVUaW1lRm9ybWF0dGVyQnVpbGRlcigpXG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIC5hcHBlbmRQYXR0ZXJuKFwieXl5eS1NTS1kZCdUJ0hIOm1tOnNzLlNTU1NTU1wiKVxuICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAucGFyc2VMZW5pZW50KClcbiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgLnBhcnNlQ2FzZUluc2Vuc2l0aXZlKClcbiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgLmFwcGVuZE9mZnNldChcIitISDpNTVwiLCBcIiswMDowMFwiKVxuICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAudG9Gb3JtYXR0ZXIoKVxuICAgICAgICAgICAgXG4gICAgcmV0dXJuIExvY2FsRGF0ZVRpbWUucGFyc2UoZGF0ZSwgZGF0ZVRpbWVGb3JtYXR0ZXIpXG59In0=)

And it is work on this online compiler:

[example2](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_kotlin_online.php)

What can be a problem?

Comment: Since your string contains a UTC offset (`+00:00`), parse it into an `OffsetDateTime`, not a `LocalDateTime`. The latter loses the offset. If you assume the offset is always zero, still parse into an `OffsetDateTime` so you can check the assumption. Next, why are you trying to make your own formatter? Just use `OffsetDateTime.parse("2023-07-17T12:05:11.03831+00:00")`. And your problem is gone. Or if you insist on throwing the offset away without checking it first, `LocalDateTime.parse("2023-07-17T12:05:11.03831+00:00", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)`.

Answer (score 3):

Failing to parse the date is the expected behaviour. The format has six `S` characters, but you only supplied five in your string.

If you want parsing to succeed even with 5 digits, you can use `appendFraction` and specify a min and max number of digits.

```
.appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
.appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 5, 6, true)
```

The reason why it succeeds in parsing *sometimes*, is probably related to [this bug](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8230136?jql=text%20%7E%20%22datetimeformatter%20fraction%22), where the minimum width of the fraction-of-second field is not checked. `SSSSSS` should have a minimum width and maximum width of 6.

So depending on the JVM version, (or Android version? I'm not too sure about how Android works) the code behaves differently. This bug is said to be fixed in Java 14, so every version after that should fail to parse the string.

Answer (score 2):

1. The pattern you defined expects six fractions of second (`S`) but the example value provides only 5 (and the fractions of second start at index 20)
2. You are trying to parse a value with an offset from UTC to a `LocalDateTime`, which won't work due to the offset

The cause for your exception is the first problem.

You can simply parse to an `OffsetDateTime` without a custom `DateTimeFormatter`:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val date = OffsetDateTime.parse("2023-07-17T12:05:11.03831+00:00")
    println(date)
}
```

Output:

```
2023-07-17T12:05:11.038310Z
```

If you need a `LocalDateTime`, get it from the `OffsetDateTime` by calling `toLocalDateTime()`.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the 6th character. But why is it sometimes work. If i have not correct pattern it must crash on all compilers and devices. don't it?

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

As [Commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77279641/kotlin-date-time-format-exception/77295302#comment136239808_77279641), parse as an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) without specifying a formatting pattern.

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2023-07-17T12:05:11.03831+00:00" )
```

## `OffsetDateTime` not `LocalDateTime`

You are using the wrong class. You are using [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) which represents simply a date with a time-of-day. That class lacks any notion of time zone or offset-from-UTC. This class does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline.

Tip: Think twice before using `LocalDateTime` unless you are really clear on why you are choosing that class. Business app programming commonly involves moments, and so should use `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime`.

Your input text represents a date with time-of-day as seen with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from the temporal meridian of UTC. So you should be parsing this input as a [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object.

Your input string complies with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for date-time text. The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating text. So no need to define any formatting pattern.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2023-07-17T12:05:11.03831+00:00" ) ;
```